# Move a remote development database to local usage

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have been using a central MS SQL database located in the cloud to develop a web site project. I have recently found myself in situations, when I need to develop without the internet connection. I want to begin to use a locally available copy of the existing database, put it in App_Data folder.

What is the correct set of steps I need to undertake to get the project to work with local DB?

For example:

1. Detach a db from an existing SQL instance.
2. Copy to a development machine.
   etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an empty shell database locally, then use one of the many schema comparison solutions available to make the local database look exactly like the cloud database.

Answer (score 2):

Moving a SQL-Server DB is not that hard. Look here for some methods to do it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546

I usually find the sp_detach + sp_attach method really easy.

Comment: How can he sp_detach a database in the cloud? Also, while detach/attach might be easy, it requires you to take the database offline, and it's by far the LEAST safe method on earth. If something goes wrong during the detach, you now have ZERO copies of your database.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is to create and regularly update your standalone copy of database using import/export. In particular MS SQL Server provides [Import/Export Wizard tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup
2. Copy backup file
3. Restore on your server
4. Restore/organise users